# Why do I get an error by trying to send a mail with c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, email

I'm trying to send an e-mail using C#, but I get this recurring error :

[image: Blockquote] 
.

Can you explain me what's wrong with my code ?

Here it is :

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");  


client.Port = 587;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Timeout = 100000;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myEmailAdress@gmail.com", "myPassword");  


MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.To.Add("receiver@gmail.com");
msg.From = new MailAddress("sender@gmail.com");
msg.Subject = "My subject";
msg.Body = "My body";  

client.Send(msg);  

MessageBox.Show("Message sent !");
```

Comment: Have you tried to run though the code and see which line fails?

Comment: Yes I did, but i didn't see anything wrong. The error says that there's a problem at Line 80 (client.Send(msg)), but I guess that's not the real problem

Comment: The FROM email address and the credentials have to be from the same account.  GMail rejects email when the credentials and From do not match to prevent hackers from spoofing emails and making an email look like it came from another source.

Comment: @jdweng I have also mentioned that on my answer as well. There are two common reason I did specified.

Comment: @ Md Farid Uddin Kiron : What you said and what I said are not the same especially for a novice.

Comment: no, my problem is still unresolved :(

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered same before.

> You are getting this error because you haven't set `ON` on `Less secure app access` for `sender@gmail.com` as you are using Gmail `SMTP` port.

***`Reason:`***

> Your email has no remotely access permission. You have to configure
>   it. Suppose you want to sent email from  `sender@gmail.com` so you
>   have set that permission `NO` to this account.

***`How To Set`:***

You could try like below

[image]

> Or can open that tab from this link directly [`Less secure app access`](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1)

***`Update:`***

As per your comment this is for you which has working perfectly since the beginning of my career

```
public object SendMail(string fromEmail, string toEmail, string mailSubject, string mailBody, string senderName, string senderPass, string attacmmentLocationPath)
        {
            try
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                //Must be change before using 
                SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

                mail.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
                mail.To.Add(toEmail);
                mail.Subject = mailSubject;
                mail.Body = mailBody;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
               // mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@attacmmentLocationPath));

                SmtpServer.Port = 587;
                SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderName, senderPass);
                SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

                SmtpServer.Send(mail);

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return ex;
            }
        }
```

Hope that would help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already tried this and it still not working :/

Comment: Hello see the updated answer, hope it would resolve your problem. Feel free to ask if you still have any problem.

Comment: It still not working.. I guess there's a problem with my network

Comment: Hello was the problem resolved? Is there anything else that I can help you with?

Answer (score 1):

This code works for gmail, it is very similar to yours with slight differences, but if you try this, and it doesn't work for you, the issue is not the code - perhaps some other network related issue that you are going to need to fix first:

```
            using (var msg = new MailMessage())
            {
                msg.From = new MailAddress("fromaddress@gmail.com");
                msg.To.Add("toaddress@gmail.com");
                msg.Subject = subject;
                msg.Body = body;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;

                using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("xxx@gmail.com","password");

                    smtp.Send(msg);
                }

            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I tried your code, but the error still appearing... I'll try to find what's wrong with my network parameters

Answer (score 0):

An SMTP client may log in using an authentication mechanism chosen among those supported by the SMTP servers.