# Access denied when sending a mail from C# programm

Tags: c#, email, smtp

I'm developing a third-party add-on to run in a program called M-Files. 
The purpose of the add-on is to send a mail with the help of an SMTP server. I created a fake SMTP server in DevelMail.com just for testing.
Testing the SMTP server from a browser works but when i run the code it gives me the following error.
Transaction failed. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client host rejected: Access denied

**Here are the SMTP information:**
**Host:** smtp.develmail.com
**SMTP Port:** 25
**TLS/SSL Port**: 465
**STARTTLS Port :** 587
**Auth types:** LOGIN, CRAM-MD5

**Here is the code:**

```
MailAddress adressFrom = new MailAddress("notification@mfiles.no", "M-Files Notification Add-on");
MailAddress adressTo = new MailAddress("majdnakhleh@live.no");
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(adressFrom, adressTo);

message.Subject = "M-Files Add-on running";
string htmlString = @"<html>
                    <body>
                    <p> Dear customer</p>
                    <p> This is a notification sent to you by using a mailadress written in a metadata property!.</p>
                    <p> Sincerely,<br>- M-Files</br></p>
                    </body>
                    </html>
                    ";
message.Body = htmlString;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Host = "smtp.develmail.com";
client.Port = 587;
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myUserName", "myPassword");
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(message);
```

Comment: You have to allow remote access on your sender email account settings. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60523276/why-do-i-get-an-error-by-trying-to-send-a-mail-with-c/60523486#60523486)  same thing has to do for your account as well. One more thing `adressFrom` and `NetworkCredential` account must be same.

Comment: Are you sure, this is a fake SMTP so i cant change any settings. And making the sender address and the credential account the same did not help.

Comment: Yes for access denial issue it is obvious that you have to allow remote access.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, this is not something I have access to do.. Just FYI, this has been tested on different servers with remote access allowed and still got the same error..

Comment: To test that what you can do is, open a gmail account and [configure it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60523276/why-do-i-get-an-error-by-trying-to-send-a-mail-with-c/60523486#60523486) then try to add that account as sender email, finally you can successfully send your email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***`Reason for the Issue:`***

> Usually, email sending option using `SMTP` encountered `Access denied`
>   because there should have a `sender email` which required to allow
>   remote access. When `SMTP` request sent from the sender email
>   it checks whether there is remote access allowed. If no, then you
>   always got `Access denied` message.

***`Solution:`***

For example let's say, you want to send email using `Gmail SMTP` in that case you do have to enable `Allow less secure apps: ON`

***`How To Set`***

You can simply browse this link [`Less secure app access`](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1) and turn that to `ON`

See the screen shot

[image]

***`Code Snippet:`***

```
    public static object SendMail(string fromEmail, string toEmail, string mailSubject, string mailBody, string senderName, string senderPass, string attacmmentLocationPath)
    {
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            //Must be change before using other than gmail smtp
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");

            mail.From = new MailAddress(fromEmail);
            mail.To.Add(toEmail);
            mail.Subject = mailSubject;
            mail.Body = mailBody;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderName, senderPass);//Enter the credentails from you have configured earlier
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return ex;
        }
    }
```

> **`Note:`** Make sure, `fromEmail` and `(senderName, senderPass)` should be same email with the credential.

Hope that would help.