# Contact US Page showing errors when try to send email (ASP.Net Core MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

This ASP.NET Core MVC code is not sending any emails.

This is ContactFormModel:

```
    public class ContactFormModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }

    }
```

This is `ContactUsController`:

[ContactUs Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdN6P.jpg)

This is the `SendMail` class:

```
namespace Alak_1.Models
{
    public class SendMail : IEmailSender
    {
        public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
        {
            using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("");
                mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                mailMessage.Body = email + htmlMessage;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(""));

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;

                System.Net.NetworkCredential networkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                networkCred.UserName = "";
                networkCred.Password = "";

                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = networkCred;
                smtp.Port = 587;

                await smtp.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, `ContactMail.cshtml` view:

[Cshtml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CITHs.jpg)

And I am getting errors like this:

[Can not send email and showing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC4UF.jpg)

Do you guys have any suggestions on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Well I got the exact reason of your error. You are creating new
> instance of `MailAddress("")` with empty value rather passing a email
> address here. You should pass sender and receiver email address
> instead.

You should modify your code like below:

```
namespace Alak_1.Models
{
    public class SendMail : IEmailSender

    {
        public async Task SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string htmlMessage)
        {
            using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(senderEmailAddess);
                mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                mailMessage.Body = email + htmlMessage;
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.To.Add(receiverEmailAddress);
                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                System.Net.NetworkCredential networkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(senderName, senderPass);
                networkCred.UserName = "";
                networkCred.Password = "";
                smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                smtp.Credentials = networkCred;
                smtp.Port = 587;
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(mailMessage);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

> ***Note:*** You are sending `new MailAddress("");` as empty which is not valid. because gmail smtp wouldn't find the `sender` and `receiver` information and
> encounter the error you got. Additionally you should add Below
> Permission:

[image]

> You can do this by openning that tab from this link directly [`Less secure app access`](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1). For more details you can [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60814553/access-denied-when-sending-a-mail-from-c-sharp-programm/60828753#60828753)

Hope it would resove your problem.