# Error: cannot convert from "string" to "MimeKit.MimeMessage"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, type-conversion, mime-message, mjml

I want to send a email

```
        public readonly IMjmlServices _mjmlServices;
            bodyBuilder.HtmlBody += $"</tr></ mj - table ></ mj - column ></ mj - section ></ mj - body ></ mjml >";
            bodyBuilder.TextBody += $"This is some plain text";
            var result = _mjmlServices.Render(bodyBuilder.HtmlBody).Result;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                try
                {
                    client.Connect("Smtp.gmail.com", 465, true);
                    client.Authenticate("", "");
                    client.Send(result.Html);
                    Console.WriteLine("----- EMAIL SENT!! -----");
                }
```

but at `client.Send(result.Html);`it is giving error saying that **Error: cannot convert from "string" to "MimeKit.MimeMessage"** like [image: this]

How to convert this *string* to *MimeKit.MimeMessage* and then send this as email?

How to convert this *string* to *MimeKit.MimeMessage* and then send this as email?

Comment: http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm

Comment: Also, please `await` `_mjmlServices.Render`, rather than using `.Result`

Comment: @gunr2171 
but this not simple HTML, I am using **MJML** framework so I cannot just add it as string

Comment: Your comment does not make sense. The parameter for `client.Send` is a `MimeMessage` object. So create a `MimeMessage` variable and populate it as you need to. See the link above.

Comment: Are you sending email using `Gmail SMTP client`? What I mean is are you using `gmail endpoint` to deliver your email?

Comment: Hello was the answer helpful? Do you still need any assistance on this?

Answer (score 0):

***`"How to convert this string to MimeKit.MimeMessage and then send this as email"`***

> I think the way you are trying to send email using `SmtpClient` is not
> correct. using `IMjmlServices` you should try below way:

**`MjmlEmailService:`**

```cs
 public readonly IMjmlServices _mjmlServices;
 public EmailController(IMjmlServices _mjml) => (_mjmlServices) = (_mjml);


 public async Task MjmlEmailService()
        {
            var prehtml = "<mjml><mj-body><mj-container><mj-section><mj-column><mj-text>Hello From MJML Service!</mj-text></mj-column></mj-section></mj-container></mj-body></mjml>";
            var result = await _mjmlServices.Render(prehtml);
            SmtpEmailProcessor(result.Html);
        }
```

> **Note:** Here you have to pass the `result.Html` from `MjmlResponse` interface which will be email body while `SMTP` request sent. Here it better to make two service separated because `MjmlEmailService` and `SmtpClient` has different concern.

**`SmtpClient:`**

```cs
public void SmtpEmailProcessor(string emailBody)
        {
            try
            {
                SmtpClient objsmtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
                objsmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                objsmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("YourEmailId", "YourEmailPassword");
                objsmtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                objsmtp.EnableSsl = true;
                MailMessage msg = new MailMessage("From Email", "To Email", "Subject: MJML Test", emailBody);
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                objsmtp.Timeout = 50000;
                objsmtp.Send(msg);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
```

**`Note:`** You can have a look on valid `SmtpClient` request [`here in this reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69021479/contact-us-page-showing-errors-when-try-to-send-email-asp-net-core-mvc)

**`Output:`**

[image]

Hope above steps guided you accordingly.